# Hide and show div in a form using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two fields in a form, the first field is a drop down menu as shown below. The second is a date picker.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="customername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Requires FPC? :</label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<select class="col-sm-12 form-control" id="fpc" name="fpc" required>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="internal_ship_date_label" class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="internal_ship_date_label" name="internal_ship_date_label">Internal Ship Date:</label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="internal_ship_date" name="internal_ship_date">
</div>
</div>
```

when the user selects option value "NO" I would like the internal_ship_date  to hide. If the user selects "Yes", I would like the internal_ship_date  to show. I would like to do this in JavaScript as I am trying to learn! Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: If you're not trying to learn JavaScript proper, you can use jQuery to make this simple. You're probably loading it already for Bootstrap. You'd probably use the `on.change` event to trigger the page update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
document.getElementById("internal_ship_date_label").style.display = ""; //to show
document.getElementById("internal_ship_date_label").style.display = "none"; //to hide
```